# How can I select only CSS classes based on two strings that have a string between them?

Tags: css, regex, css-selectors

How can I create a selector that matches any set of two specific strings with a dynamic string in between them?:

e.g.

```
[class*="animation-"**"-infinite"] {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

So it would be able to target these classes:

```
class="animation-hover-infinite"
class="animation-scale-infinite"
class="animation-opacity-infinite-somethingElse"
class="animation-etc-infinite withSomeOtherClass"
```

But not target this:

```
class="animation-something"
class="something-infinite"
```

Is this possible? Or are there other CSS selectors that can make this happen?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not something that CSS attribute selectors support. You can see the currently supported ones on the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: You will need JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for start and end, if that helps.

```css
div[class^="animation-"][class$="-infinite"] {
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background: red;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-blabla-infinite"></div>
<div class="animation-blabla-infinites"></div>
<div class="zanimation-blabla-infinite"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although this only allows it if the class is specifically has animation-blabla-infinite. Is it possible to make it work with class="animation-blabla-infinite another-class"

Comment: This do not work for `class="animation-opacity-infinite-somethingElse"`

Comment: @ehsan and that wasn't the question. any set of two specific strings with a dynamic string in between them. I didn't even look at the examples. Now that I do, they don't match the initial request.

Comment: I would probably use *="animation-" and *="-infinite" because op said with something in between. I think that would be the closest thing you could achieve with only css. In your code it won't work if there's another classname at the end or start.